# RSS Feed Error - Displays Wednesday December 31, 1969

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I've been trying to parse a wordpress feed and show it on a page.
But The function just displays Wednesday December 31,1969 and nothing else. 
I've looked at other solutions but still get the same output, even when I run the code from different servers (in case there is a hosting php/library problem)

What am I missing?

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.pushingsocial.com/feed');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array ( 
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
);
array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
$title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
$link = $feed[$x]['link'];
$description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
$date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it [works fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L4J9mL) for me. Try adding `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script and see if it outputs any error messages?

Comment: var_dump($feed[0]); What does it display ?

Comment: I just figured out what is happening my host doesn't allow fopen so I had to convert the script to CURL.  Now it works fine.